# How can I Edit the zoom level of datalayer visibility in openstreetmap

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, leaflet, openstreetmap

I've installed openstreetmap-website/leaflet from github.

How can I Edit the zoom level of datalayer visibility, when I check "show map data" for editing on my server I can't see that data on 12-0 level, how can I find the place in JS/RB code where I can fix it and get it working on 9-15 level?

All that I know is that leaflet-zooming depends on browser height/width at the moment, when I shrink browser window to 500*500 DataLayer appears!

Answer (score 1):

max_request_area option in config/application.yml is set to 0.25
setting it to 50 for example will give the result!
thanks to Tom Hughes via https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/issues/824#issuecomment-61768211

also don't forget to:

**rake tmp:cache:clear**
in app folder to clear the cache
& 
**service apache2 restart** to restart the passenger